# Double Integral/Change of variables problem

Tags: integration

Not sure how to solve this, as far as I know it's one of the two (Or both, possibly) ways in the title. The problem is this:

Calculate the area between the functions:

$y^2=2px$, $y^2=2qx$, ($0<p<q$)

$x^2=2sy$, $x^2=2ry$, ($0<r<s$)

I know this can be solved by using a normal integral and divided the area into three parts, but I'm looking for the better/more efficient option.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! On SE sites thanks are usually omitted, as they are implied by the question itself. It is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $u=\frac{y^2}{2x}$ and $v=\frac{x^2}{2y}$ so that $p<u<q$ and $r<v<s$ with $J=\frac{\partial(u, v)}{\partial(x, y)}=-\frac{3}{4}$. So the area is $\frac{4}{3}.(q-p)(s-r)$, where the factor $4/3$ comes from the absolute value of the reciprocal of $J$..